# Total page size is different in each location

Tags: php, wordpress

I have web-site on wordpress. It was 5.8 mb page size. I optimized some images and uploaded them back. Page size should be 2 times less. But it isnt.
But i tested web-site in europe server and it showed 2.8mb page size. Usa shows 5.8mb still.

i tested here https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/d5WYQO/http://www.jc-plumbers.com/

?

Comment: when i watch image in media. It shows image that is optimized(with less size)

Comment: Question is a bit confusing. If you actually have 2 different servers with nominally the same pages, maybe one has compression turned on in Apache and one doesn't?

Comment: Be sure there no cache on the server's side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the problem.

This [image](http://www.jc-plumbers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/NRgfuol.png) (NRgfuol.png) it's coming from CloudFlare. CloudFlare has the old version (3.8 MB) while the new one has a smaller size (1.7 MB).

It seems that CF won't respect `no-cache` if you have a `__cfduid` cookie set, so Pingdom is getting the cached version instead of a fresh one.

Potential solution is to rename files whenever you optimize them, so you can avoid this long lasting caches.

[image: Pingdom is getting a HIT from CloudFlare]